# Countdown in React App seems to countdown exponentially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to make a simple countdown button using React JS. It is almost complete, however, it counts down immediately when I want it to only start the countdown once the button is clicked.

The default value is 10. If you do not input your own value, greater than 0, than it will countdown from 10.

Below is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './app.css';
import { Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Countdown extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            time: ''
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({time: 10});
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(() => this.registerTime(this.state.time - 1), 1000);
    }

    registerTime(time){
        if(time >= 0){
            this.setState({time});
        }
    }

    countdown(){
        const textVal = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
        if(isNaN(textVal) || textVal == '' || textVal == ' ' || textVal <= 0){
            alert("Please enter a numeric value greater than 0!");
        } else{
            this.registerTime(textVal);
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="app">
                <h1>This is going to be a Countdown!</h1>
                <div>{this.state.time}</div>
                <Form inline>
                    <FormControl 
                        id="time-input"
                        placeholder="new time" 
                        onChange={event => {
                                if(event.target.value != '' && event.target.value != ' '){
                                    this.setState({time: event.target.value});
                                }
                            }}
                        onKeyPress={event => {
                                if(event.key === 'Enter'){this.countdown();}
                            }}
                        />
                    <Button onClick={event => this.countdown()} >Start</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Countdown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started interval right away when you mount the component. I have created a working demo for you in `codepen`. 
https://codepen.io/RutulPatel7077/pen/yRpzVB

Answer (score 0):

Might it have something to do with the componentDidMount method where setInterval calls on the registerTime every 1 second?